# Import methods of the components instead of the binding function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
export default withModalMounter(injectIntl(Poll));
```

I want to extract **Poll** while importing it in a different component. It looks that that while importing I am just able to import **withModalMounter** component and not the methods of Poll.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, not able to import method of Poll

Comment: When I import Poll  , withModalMounter gets imported

Comment: withModalMounter wraps Poll so definitely you would see withModalMounter after importing.

Comment: I want to import them in both forms in different places. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to import Poll component without withModalMounter too. You can export it like below

```
const withInjectIntl = injectIntl(Poll);
export { withInjectIntl as Poll };
export default withModalMounter(withInjectIntl);
```

Post this you can import it like

```
import PollWithMounter, { Poll } from 'path/to/poll';
```